# Substutution of Ansatz of an ODE

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions

I am only beginning to learn to use Mathematica, and got stuck while trying to implement what is apparently a simple substitution rule.

So I have a second order ODE in f, and I want to put in the ansatz`f = r*phi`, a multiplicative ansatz. I thought `ReplaceAll` followed by `Simplify` would do the job, but apparently this doesn't expand and simplify the derivatives. I want the replaced ODE to be in terms of r and phi only, no f, so that I can then manipulate them further. How to accomplish this?

Also, a side question, does someone know of a way to get to display the ODE in the proper form, all y'', y' and y terms grouped together? (for aesthetic purposes only)

The code:

```
J[k_,f_] := f''[k] +f'[k] +f[k]
J[k,f] //ReplaceAll[f[k] -> r[k] phi[k]] //Simplify
```

The output is :

```
r[k] phi[k] + f'[k] + f''[k]
```

I want the derivatives to be expanded/evaluated too.

Comment: Copy your Mathematica code here: what's the ODE? what's the ansatz you tried? What was the output? What did you intend to achieve?

Comment: Search for dchange on this site.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: As Quantum dot implies, problems with code generally require the code to be posted to get help.

Comment: @QuantumDot Code and Output added

Comment: Try `f''[k] + f'[k] + f[k] /. f -> Function[k, r[k] phi[k]]`.

Comment: @J. M. Wow, that works! Thanks a lot. Could you perhaps add some explanation too? Also why did the ReplaceAll not work as expected?

Comment: With your syntax (delayed assignment of J), you could also do with J[k, r[k] phi[k]]

Comment: @Peltio It almost works that way, but the OP has `J` set up so that `f` has to be a (pure-ish) function.

Answer (score 3):

Two ways:

```
J[k_, f_] := f''[k] + f'[k] + f[k]
J[k, r[#] phi[#] &] // Simplify
```

Or

```
J[k, f] /. f -> (r[#] phi[#] &) // Simplify
```

Out:

```
(*  {2 phi'[k] r'[k] + r[k] (phi'[k] + phi''[k]) + phi[k] (r[k] + r'[k] + r''[k])}  *)
```

One can go further, too:

```
J[k, f]/f[k] /. f -> (r[#] phi[#] &) // Expand;
% /. {r'[k] -> lr'[k] r[k], phi'[k] -> lphi'[k] phi[k], 
    r''[k] -> (lr''[k] + lr'[k]^2) r[k], 
    phi''[k] -> (lphi''[k] + lphi'[k]^2) phi[k]} // Factor;
% /. lr -> (Integrate[u[#], #] - lphi[#] &) // Expand
(*  1 + u[k] + u[k]^2 + u'[k]  *)
```

where $\int u(k) \;dk = \log r(k) + \log \phi(k)$.

Comment: Just noticed J.M. and Peltio had similar. suggestions in comments.